# query not executing on production while working on development

Tags: mysql

I have select query in `mysql` which is perfectly working in localhost environment, however when post in `Adminer` for productions it throws error

```
select * from `history` where `id` = '114' and `date` like '%2020-02%'
```

date is Date type in DB

error is

> Error in query (1525): Incorrect DATE value: '%2020-02%'

while working perfectly in local

Comment: your error explicitly said about the issue so what you have not understand?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin this query is working in localhost perfectly with same values

Comment: check your local db column data type

Comment: both are same Date

Comment: as you are using date so wild card comparison making no sesnce here

Comment: This query should work. The reason for the error is probably [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95780) in 8.0.16, which is already fixed.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel possibly my adminer version is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use month and year function as you want to pick all the rows of the month feb of the year 2020 so get month and year

```
select h.* from `history` h where `id` = '114' and 
month(`date`)=2
and year(`date`)=2020
```

Comment: This answer shouldn't be downvoted since it fulfills the OP's desired result

Answer (score 1):

Do not use string methods over date values (you'll loose index use capability). Use

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM history 
WHERE id = 114 
  AND `date` >= '2020-02-01'
  AND `date` < '2020-03-01';
```